# Overriding input class in TextField using makeStyles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, makestyles

When trying to override the **padding** property in *TextField* input using *MakeStyles*, a new class is created called **.makeStyles-input** which is priorotized under **MuiOutlinedInput-root** class.

How do I inject a property into the **input** class (not depending on whether the *OutlineInput* or *FilledInput* component is used, and without using the **important** css tag)?

```
import { TextField } from '@mui/material';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles'; 

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  input: {
    padding: 0,
  },
});

function CustomTextField(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <TextField
      InputProps={{
        classes: {
          root: classes.input,
        },
      }}
      {...props}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that MUI 4 allows for that level of customization on their [TextField](https://v4.mui.com/api/text-field/) component.

My recommendation comes from the [MUI (v4) docs](https://v4.mui.com/api/text-field/#advanced-configuration), I would be to use the `InputBase` component to customize, or use one of the three input variants that do allow for more customization, namely the [OutlinedInput](https://v4.mui.com/api/outlined-input/), [FilledInput](https://v4.mui.com/api/filled-input/) or [Input](https://v4.mui.com/api/input/) components.

`TextField` is an abstraction on top of those components, so you lose a bit of customization due to the fact that a lot of the props are decided for you.

Look at the [Google Maps input form demo on MUI](https://v4.mui.com/components/text-fields/#customized-inputs), it's a good starter for what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm using mui 5

Comment: @AmitaiFensterheim I assumed you were using 4 since you were using `makeStyles`. The advice still stands, but I would recommend that you move over to another styling solution such as MUI's own `styled`. Regardless, you're going to have to use one of the components mentioned above to get more customization.